# Deriving least squares coefficients for curve of form $y=a/(x^2+b)$

Tags: statistics, least-squares

I am trying to derive the coefficients $a$ and $b$ for a least squares curve of the form $y=\frac{a}{x^2+b}$

To start I have written $$S=\sum_i(y_i-y)^2=\sum_i\left(y_i-\frac{a}{x_i^2+b}\right)^2=\sum_i\left(y_i^2-\frac{2a y_i}{x_i^2+b}+\frac{a^2}{(x_i^2+b)^2}\right) \\S=\sum_iy_i^2-2a\sum_i\frac{y_i}{x_i^2+b}+a^2\sum_i\frac{1}{(x_i^2+b)^2}$$

Now the way I have seen it done for the line $y=a+bx$ is they minimize $S$ with respect to both $a$ and $b$, applying that for this curve gives the two constraint equations:

$$0=a\sum_i\frac{1}{(x_i^2+b)^2}-\sum_i\frac{y_i}{x_i^2+b}\\
0=-a\sum_i\frac{1}{(x_i^2+b)^3}+\sum_i\frac{y_i}{x_i^2+b}$$

Summing these together we find $$0=a\left(\sum_i\frac{1}{(x_i^2+b)^2}-\sum_i\frac{1}{(x_i^2+b)^3}\right)$$
Since $a\neq 0$ we must have $$\sum_i\frac{1}{(x_i^2+b)^2}=\sum_i\frac{1}{(x_i^2+b)^3}$$ Which seems to imply $$(x_i^2+b)^2=(x_i^2+b)^3$$ and unfortunately there doesnt appear to be a constant $b$ that solves this equation. Did I make a mistake somewhere or is this the result?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Starting with a rather silly sentence : since the model is nonlinear with respect to $b$, by the end, you will need a nonlinear regression and, as usual, you will need reasonable starting guesses for the parameters.

You can get these estimates in a preliminary step
$$y=\frac{a}{x^2+b} \implies \frac 1y=\frac {x^2} a+\frac ba$$ So, defining for each $(x_i,y_i)$ data points, new variables $t_i=x_i^2$ and $z_i=\frac 1{y_i}$, you have $$z=\alpha\, t+\beta$$ and, from the corresponding linear regression, you will get, as estimates $a=\frac 1 \alpha$ and  $b=\frac \beta \alpha$.

If you do not want to use nonlinear regression, you can reduce the problem to a nasty equation in $b$.

Using Rohan's expressions, let us define 
$$S_1=\sum \frac{y_i}{x_i^2+b} \qquad S_2=\sum \frac{1}{(x_i^2+b)^2}$$
$$S_3=\sum \frac{y_i}{(x_i^2+b)^2} \qquad S_4= \sum \frac{1}{(x_i^2+b)^3}$$ Eliminating $a$, you then need to to find the zero of function  $$f(b)=S_2\, S_3-S_1 S_4$$ Since you have the estimate, you could use it as the starting point of Newton method with analytical derivatives since $$f'(b)=S_2S'_3+S'_2S_3-S_1S'_4-S'_1S_4$$ where will appear other summations (I let you the task of writing them - they are not difficult). The iterative process will converge very fast. So $b$ and then $a$.

**Edit**

For illustration purposes, consider the following data set
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
x & y \\
 0 & 46 \\
 1 & 46 \\
 2 & 45 \\
 3 & 43 \\
 4 & 41 \\
 5 & 38 \\
 6 & 36 \\
 7 & 33 \\
 8 & 30 \\
 9 & 28
\end{array}
\right)$$ The preliminary step leads to $z=0.000176905 t+0.0216373$ from which the estimates $a=5652.76$ and $b=122.310$.

Starting with this guess, the iterates of Newton method will be
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
n & b_n \\
 0 & 122.31000 \\
 1 & 121.84307 \\
 2 & 121.85174
\end{array}
\right)$$ from which $a=5635.22$. A nonlinear regression would have be providing exactly the same values for the parameters.

Answer (score 1):

If you actually had to run this regression, you would use this model:
$$
ln(y_i) = ln(a) - ln(x_i^2+b)+u_i
$$
where $u_i$ is the error term. The sum of squared residuals is
$$
S =\sum_i(ln(y_i) - ln(\hat{a}) + ln(x_i^2+\hat{b}))^2 
$$
where I am using the usual notation for an estimator.  Then
$$
\partial S/\partial \hat{a} = 0 \\
\sum_i(ln(y_i) - ln(\hat{a}) + ln(x_i^2+\hat{b})) =0\\
ln(\hat{a}) = \sum_i(ln(y_i)+ln(x_i^2+\hat{b}))/n
$$
where $n$ is the number of observations. Also, 
$$
\partial S/\partial \hat{b} = 0 \\
\sum_i\dfrac{ln(y_i) - ln(\hat{a}) + ln(x_i^2+\hat{b}))}{(x_i^2+\hat{b})} =0\\
$$
The latter expression is not linear in $\hat{b}$.  So I do not see an easy algebraic solution for $\hat{a}$ and $\hat{b}$.  One would not expect the solution to be linear in the parameters because the original functional form is itself non-linear.  Maybe someone else can pick it up from here.

Comment: In my opinion, you make the problem more complex than the original one. Eliminating $a$ is not a problem and, for any of the formulations, we need to solve for $b$. If we use what you propose will just lead to an approximation of $b$. Remember that what is measured is $y$ and not any of its possible transforms.

Comment: @Claude Leibovici, I see your point, but I run lots of regressions.  The computer understands $y$ and $ln(y)$ equally well.  But your right, I’ll have a problem if any y is negative.  Still the data are trying to fit a curve whose value at $x=0$ is $a/b$.

Comment: It is not the problem of the logarithms. It is the fact that you are minimizing the sum of the squares based on $\log(y)$ while what is measured is $y$. The log transform introduces a bias.

Answer (score 0):

We have $$\frac{\partial S}{\partial a} = -2\sum \frac{y_i}{x_i^2+b}+2a\sum \frac{1}{(x_i^2+b)^2}$$ $$\frac{\partial S}{\partial b} = 2a \sum \frac{y_i}{(x_i^2+b)^2} -2a^2 \sum \frac{1}{(x_i^2+b)^3}$$

Comment: ... and though you can solve either of these $=0$ for $a$, the result will be a very complicated rational function (in $b$) $=0$; you won't get a closed-form solution.  Numerical methods will be needed.

Comment: a=0 will result in a value of 0 everywhere for the curve. Also this is just a non-simplified version of my constraint equations.

Comment: $a=0$ makes $\partial S/\partial b = 0$ but not $\partial S/\partial a = 0$ in general.

Comment: But $y=a/(x^2+b)$? Oh I see your original edit now oops.